# How do I change the transparent image background grid in sublime text to different colors

Tags: configuration, sublimetext3, sublimetext

When I get a preview of transparent PNGs in Sublime text - I find it hard to see the content if it is white because of the grey chequer board pattern. Is there a way for me to configure that? I need to change it to darker colours.
[image: Sublime Text Image preview chequer board pattern with a white text transparent PNG]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problem here, did you solve this issue?