# Image preview in Sublime Text: how to turn checkerboard background to editor's background for transparent images?

Tags: sublimetext3

I use Sublime Text to preview images that I produce with Python code. I need the background of the images to be transparent, but when I open them in the Sublime Text image preview, a transparency checkboard background appears that make the pictures sometimes hard to read (screenshot on right hand side).

Is there any way to set the background to the natural editor background color (left hand side)? This question appeared two years ago in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983985/how-do-i-change-the-transparent-image-background-grid-in-sublime-text-to-differe) but had no answer so far.

[image: sublime text image preview transparent background]

Comment: What file-format are those images ?

Comment: In this case, png

Comment: Can you make a duplicate ? For example `png` and `jpg`. Let `png` be transparent, but open `jpg` in sublime.